# Django Foreign Key Null and unqiue togehter , plus lowercase

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have a Category Model that has a Foreign  to itself and can have Null values.

I know that unique together doesn't work when Foreign key is Null. Also I want to check if they are duplicate, unique together indifferent of case(lower,up, combinations) and that the parent and the child to not have identical names.

I found some partial solutions on the site but are not great and don't cover all my situations. Another thing, I do the clean on model, because I will have categories in Admin, so no form or view under my control.

Now I have an error on 'name__iexact" and don't understand why because 'name==self.name" works.

`"NameError: name '_' is not defined"`

self.pk=pk ; I check this because in case of update, it will find the current instance that I edit and trow ValidationError, which is not ok.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent category')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        if not self.parent:
            exists = self.__class__.objects.filter(~Q(pk=self.pk), name__iexact=self.name).exists()
            if exists:
                raise ValidationError(_('Duplicate Category Name with No Parent'), code='duplicate_no_parent')
        if self.name.lower() == self.parent.name.lower():
            raise ValidationError(_('Category Name the same as Parent Category Name'), code='duplicate_as_parent')

        return cleaned_data
```

---

Error for name__iexact:

```
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name '_' is not defined

File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 551, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 224, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1508, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1408, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1440, in _changeform_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 386, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 408, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
  File "D:\DevEnv\PythonEnv\Django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1234, in full_clean
    self.clean()
  File "D:\DevProj\Learn\Django\ph_work\categories\models.py", line 21, in clean
    raise ValidationError(_('Duplicate Category Name with No Parent'), code='duplicate_no_parent')
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it, and put full error stack

```
exists = self.__class__.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(name__iexact=self.name).exists()
```

Comment: if form.is_valid():
\forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
forms\forms.py", line 386, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
\forms\models.py", line 408, in _post_clean
    self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
\db\models\base.py", line 1234, in full_clean
    self.clean()
\categories\models.py", line 20, in clean
    raise ValidationError(_('Duplicate Category Name with No Parent'), code='duplicate_no_parent')
NameError: name '_' is not defined

Comment: add import `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for the same string value I suggest using the "is" operator:

```
if self.name.lower() is self.parent.lower()
```

In this way you are testing to see if they share the same memory address, which is fine because Python stores strings who have the same value at one memory address.

Comment: actually is: self.name.lower() == self.parent.name.lower(), and using "is" instead of == will fail